# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'

Tags: python

I am unable to use `ggplot` package in python .

```py
import pandas as pd

from ggplot import *


import pandas as pd

from ggplot import *
```

It returns:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'

Answer (score 20):

I changed `import` commands for `pandas` modules in `ggplot` source files on my PC and it worked for me. You can find the locations for those on your PC in your error message. For me it was `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ggplot`
The files I have changed:
In `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ggplot\utils.py`
From

```py
date_types = (
    pd.tslib.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

to:

```
date_types = (
    pd._tslib.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

And in `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ggplot\stats\smoothers.py` the same change as above and in addition:

```py
from pandas.lib import Timestamp
```

to:

```py
from pandas import Timestamp
```

```py
date_types = (
    pd.tslib.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

to:

```
date_types = (
    pd.Timestamp,
    pd.DatetimeIndex,
    pd.Period,
    pd.PeriodIndex,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.time
)
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks. However, for the last replacement I opted for
Change from pandas.lib import Timestamp to from pandas import Timestamp.
as seen here https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/662#issuecomment-526826798

Comment: Great! I wonder why they didn't fix it yet in the package itself..

Comment: I think it is not maintained anymore, checkout plotnine(https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine)

Answer (score 3):

I found this problem in colab.
To solve this problem simply click the link to util.py,smoother.py in error notification.

1. Fix some config in util.py :
   pd.tslib.Timestamp --> pd.Timestamp

then ctrl-s to save new configuration

2. Fix some config in smoothers.py :
   from pandas.lib import Timestamp  --> from pandas import Timestamp

then ctrl-s to save new configuration
after fix all above. Run this cell again.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
 import rpy2
```

There is an issue therein, but at least you'll get it working

---

My advice is to go with ggplot2 directly in R. It's hard to get this working even with pandas correctly installed and the Syntax isn't trivial

Comment: error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement r2py.

Comment: It's complicated and channel r rpy2 will not install just go with R

Comment: Switching programming languages is potentially a great deal of effort.  It really does not address @kamal-sri's issue, an issue using Python.

Answer (score -1):

Installing `plotnine` fixed the issue for me.

```
pip install plotnine
```